# How to handle global variables when a page gets ajaxed in

Tags: javascript, ajax, module

I have a shared layout page that loads a bundle.js or possible some global js files (jquery or whatnot).  The page then ajax in applications.  Each application needs to reference a module or variable in the bundle.js file that has already been loaded.  Keep in mind that the are 2 separate projects, and both have their own bundle.js file.  How would i go about this if the applications are using require('module').